# Finding ideal fluid flow with a boundary

Tags: complex-analysis, fluid-dynamics

I need to find the stream lines of an ideal fluid flow with the given potential of $F(z)=z^2=x^2-y^2+i2xy$ on the upper half of the Cartesian plane.

I have determined that the velocity of the fluid must be $\overline{F'(z)}=2x-i2y$ however this has does not fit the constraint because the fluid has a non-zero imaginary component at the line $\Im(z)=0$ and thus violates the boundary.  It seems like you cannot have this potential and this boundary condition because the fluid would be forced to flow through a boundary.

How do I make the fluid fit the boundary?  How does one do this for a general potential and boundary condition?

Comment: may be you can try the method of images.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out, so heres an answer for anyone confused like me in the future (probably still me).

$F'(z)$ is the derivative with respects to $z$ so the velocity is $\overline{F'(z)} = 2\bar{z}$.  This fits our constraint.

Essentially when asked to find the fluid flow of a potential with a constraint, the constraint should not have any impact on the solution other than to provide a domain.  Either the potential fits the constraint or it does not.  You cannot make a potential fit an arbitrary constraint (unless the potential is zero everywhere), which is where the confusion I had was coming from.

Answer (score -1):

The streamlines should look like as the following:

[image]

> which belongs to a family of curves $$2xy=c$$

Comment: I am aware of what the answer is. I would like to know how to get the answer.

Comment: $$F(z)=\phi(x,y)+i\psi(x,y)$$ where $\phi(x,y)$ is the velocity potential and $\psi(x,y)$ is the stream function.  $\overline{F'(z)}$ is the complex velocity field.  The streamlines a family of $\psi(x,y)=c$